# Exception ExcepcionInditex is not compatible with throws clause in PricesApi.listarPrices(String, String, OffsetDateTime)

Tags: java-8

Estoy montando un proyecto apiFirts open api. el generado de openapi crea las fechas con la clase OffsetDateTime. El problema viene cuando quiero usar OffsetDateTime en la implementacion del controller ya uqe me da el error del titulo, sin embargo si uso LocalDateTime no hay problema.

Esta es la interfaz creada automaticamente

```
    @Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-10-31T14:00:48.235937100+01:00[Europe/Madrid]")
@Validated
@Tag(name = "Prices", description = "the Prices API")
public interface PricesApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    /**
     * GET /prices/{brandId}/{productId} : Obtener todos los productos por ID de empresa, producto y la fecha de inicio de su precio
     * Obtener todos los productos dado el ID de la empresa, el del producto y la fecha de inicio de su precio
     *
     * @param brandId   Id de la empresa a la que pertenece (required)
     * @param productId   Id del producto buscado (required)
     * @param fechaInicio  Fecha de inicio del precio (required)
     * @return Ok (status code 200)
     *         or No encontrado (status code 204)
     *         or Bd no accesible (status code 500)
     */
    @Operation(
        operationId = "listarPrices",
        summary = "Obtener todos los productos por ID de empresa, producto y la fecha de inicio de su precio",
        description = "Obtener todos los productos dado el ID de la empresa, el del producto y la fecha de inicio de su precio",
        tags = { "Prices" },
        responses = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Ok", content = {
                @Content(mediaType = "*/*", schema = @Schema(implementation = Price.class))
            }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "204", description = "No encontrado"),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Bd no accesible")
        }
    )
    @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        value = "/prices/{brandId}/{productId}",
        produces = { "*/*" }
    )
    default ResponseEntity<Price> listarPrices(
        @Parameter(name = "brandId", description = "  Id de la empresa a la que pertenece", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("brandId") String brandId,
        @Parameter(name = "productId", description = "  Id del producto buscado", required = true, in = ParameterIn.PATH) @PathVariable("productId") String productId,
        @NotNull @Parameter(name = "fechaInicio", description = " Fecha de inicio del precio", required = true, in = ParameterIn.QUERY) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "fechaInicio", required = true) @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) OffsetDateTime fechaInicio
    ) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("*/*"))) {
                    String exampleString = "{ \"price_list\" : \"2\", \"precio\" : 21.99, \"productID\" : \"35455\", \"endDate\" : \"2023-05-01T14:30:00Z\", \"id\" : 1, \"priority\" : 1, \"curr\" : \"EUR\", \"startDate\" : \"2000-01-23T04:56:07.000+00:00\", \"brand_id\" : \"1\" }";
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "*/*", exampleString);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }

}
```

Este es mi servicio que tiene un trow exception

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class ServicioImplPrice implements ServicioPrice {
  private static final Logger logger =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServicioImplPrice.class);

  private RepositorioPrice repositorio;

  @Override
  public List<Price> listarPrices(String idEmpresa, String productId,
      OffsetDateTime fechaInicio) throws ExcepcionInditex {
    logger.info("Hacemos la llamada al repositorio");

    List<Price> lista = repositorio.findByBrandIdAndProductIDAndStartDate(
        idEmpresa, productId, fechaInicio);
    if (lista.isEmpty()) {
      logger.info("la lista viene vacia");

      throw new ExcepcionInditex(204, "El articulo no esta en la BD");
    }
    return lista;
  }
}
```

El controller

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
public class ControladorPrice implements PricesApi {

  private static final Logger logger =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControladorPrice.class);
  private ServicioPrice servicio;

  private MapperPrice mapper;

  @Override
  @Operation(
      summary = "Obtener todos los productos por ID de empresa, producto y la fecha de inicio de su precio",
      tags = {"Prices"},
      description = "Obtener todos los productos dado el ID de la empresa, el del producto y la fecha de inicio de su precio")
  @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Ok",
      content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Price.class)))
  @ApiResponse(responseCode = "204", description = "No encontrado",
      content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Void.class)))
  @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Bd no accesible",
      content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = Void.class)))
  @GetMapping("/prices/{brandId}/{productId}")
  public ResponseEntity<List<PriceDTO>> listarPrices(
      @PathVariable("brandId") @Parameter(
          description = "  Id de la empresa a la que pertenece",
          required = true) String brandId,
      @PathVariable("productId") @Parameter(
          description = "  Id del producto buscado",
          required = true) String productId,
      @RequestParam("fechaInicio") @Parameter(
          description = " Fecha de inicio del precio") @DateTimeFormat(
              pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") OffsetDateTime fechaInicio)
      throws ExcepcionInditex {
    logger
        .info("Llamada al servicio, mapeamos la repuesta para mostrar el DTO");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(
        servicio.listarPrices(brandId, productId, fechaInicio).stream()
            .map(mapper::mapeoADTO).toList(),
        HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

y la gestion de errores

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControladorErrores {

  @ExceptionHandler(ExcepcionInditex.class)
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleExcepcionServicio(ExcepcionInditex ex) {
    HttpStatus status = (ex.getCodigoError() == 204) ? HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), status);
  }
}
```